# vs 2015 comunity deploye error Could not locate the appxrecipe file

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1-universal

i'm truing to run a  cordova app using vs 2015 community the deplooy failed with the following error 
 **vs 2015 Could not locate the appxrecipe file. You may need to build your project**

*while it was working fine before*

here is the out

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.4.0 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.16
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.3.3 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: F:\#01.Hager\#01.work\Projects\Wesseya\Merge1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Windows Phone (Universal)\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: F:\#01.Hager\#01.work\Projects\Wesseya\Merge1\BlankCordovaApp1\bin\Windows Phone (Universal)\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Windows Phone (Universal)
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: windows
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: F:\#01.Hager\#01.work\Projects\Wesseya\Merge1\BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Hager\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AppHostLocalDebugger
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,build.json,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png,config.xml
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Platform windows already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: windows
2>------ Deploy started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
2>Could not locate the appxrecipe file. You may need to build your project.
2>Deployment failed.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows 10 then change the config.xml windows target version from 8.1 to 10
this will let the app work on windows 10 but on 8 I couldn't find yet

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in windows 8.1 app using VS2015. By changing the windows target version as Windows 8.1 in config.xml solved my issue.